# MySQL - Query containing many case statements in the select very slow

Tags: mysql, case

I have a query which contains many case statements in the select it looks something like this...

```
SELECT 
    ('2017-41') AS yearweek_week_1, 
    ('09/10/2017') AS date_week_1, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `created_at` > DATE_SUB('2017-10-02 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `created_at` < DATE_SUB('2017-10-09 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN my_user_id ELSE NULL END) AS total_week_1, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `created_at` > DATE_SUB('2017-10-02 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `created_at` < DATE_SUB('2017-10-09 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN my_user_id ELSE NULL END) AS distinct_week_1,
    ...
    // all weeks between 1 and 52 between here...
    ('2018-40') AS yearweek_week_52, 
    ('01/10/2018') AS date_week_52, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `created_at` > DATE_SUB('2018-09-24 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `created_at` < DATE_SUB('2018-10-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN my_user_id ELSE NULL END) AS total_week_52, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `created_at` > DATE_SUB('2018-09-24 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `created_at` < DATE_SUB('2018-10-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN my_user_id ELSE NULL END) AS distinct_week_52
FROM my_table
WHERE my_group_id = 123123
AND created_at > '2017-10-02 00:00:00'
```

Here's the table create syntax if it helps:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `my_table_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `my_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `my_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`my_login_id`),
  KEY `my_user_id` (`my_user_id`),
  KEY `my_group_id` (`my_group_id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `my_group_id_2` (`my_group_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `my_user_id_2` (`my_user_id`,`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_groups` FOREIGN KEY (`my_group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users` FOREIGN KEY (`my_user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So there's 104 case statements in the select which is making it very slow.

Is there a better way to write this query, or optimise the table?

Using EXPLAIN results in the following

```
id  select_type table     type  possible_keys                          key 
key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      my_table  ref   my_group_id,created_at,my_group_id_2    my_group_id_2  5  const  1789636  Using index condition
```

Comment: Better use explain on your query..

Comment: Added the result of EXPLAIN

Comment: Why do you need them in columns? If you don't mind it seem regular `GROUP BY WEEK()` and your `CREATE TABLE` statement is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little over your head, but bear with me.  MySQL has some nice power when working with @ variables inline within the query.   Here is the query first, then I'll describe its components.

```
select 
      @WeekFrom := date_add( @WeekFrom, interval 7 day ) WeekBeginning,
      date_add( @WeekFrom, interval 7 day ) WeekEnding,
      concat( @FiscalYr, '-',  @WeekNum ) AS ShowDate,
      @FiscalYr := @FiscalYr + case when @WeekNum = 52 then 1 else 0 end as NextFYCheck,
      @WeekNum := case when @WeekNum = 52 then 1 else @WeekNum +1 end as PrepNextWeekCycle
   from
      my_table MT,
      ( select 
              @WeekFrom := date_sub( '2017-10-01', interval 7 day ), 
              @WeekNum := 41,
              @FiscalYr := 2017 ) sqlvars
     limit 52
```

You can think of it as an in-line program within the query.  You can set the values using := assignment and store the result as a column name, just to be used again as the new value for the next record being processed.

Next, By doing this, I would not hard-code all your 52 week year as it would be a total PITA to change for next week cycle and worrying about the begin/end dates representing the week period in question.  To resolve this, I have written a pre-query that uses these two components to build out a fiscal year.

Break this down. I start with a query of the "my_Table" and limit 52 records as 52 weeks in a fiscal year.

Next, I am declaring a sub-select to declare the @ MySQL variables to be used.  I start with 1 WEEK BEFORE (via date_sub) the actual week you want represented.  So if your fiscal year starts 1-Oct-2017, that is what is within quotes and I subtract 7 days.  Next I hard-set your fiscal week number (week 41), then also set the Fiscal year to 2017.

Now, the fields. The @WeekFrom will represent the beginning of the week, so take whatever the last value was and add 7 days to it for identifying the beginning of the week for the given fiscal week.  Now, I can take that date result and add 7 days to identify the END OF THE WEEK LESS THAN Date (explain shortly).  Then build out the date to be shown as FiscalYear-WeekNumber format.  Once all that is done, Now I can see if I am about to advance into the next fiscal year (2018) on the next record processed.  This would only be done when I just finished processing week #52.  If so, add 1 to the fiscal year representation.  Finally, I can add 1 to the Week number, but if I just finished week #52, set the counter back to week 1.  Ex: Fiscal Year 2017-52, next cycle would be 2018-1.

Now the dates. Since you have date/time fields, lets look at the calendar Oct 1, 2017 is Sunday.  So without explicit time, assumes 12:00am.  You want all transactions that occurred WITHIN that week.  Hence I am adding 7 days which gets us to Oct 8th.  But the final WHERE clause (in the next query) will test the date LESS THAN Oct 8th.  So this makes things inclusive on Oct 7th up to and including 11:59:59pm.  So now you don't have to worry about time portion components.

So now, the above query if run on its own merits will build out and show a fiscal year calendar with begin/end dates and the show dates and order by for actual date sequence.

Now the next part.  You want the activity, do a simple JOIN based on the dates and where the user ID in question.  Take the entire query above and insert within explicitly where below WITHIN the parenthesis (and keep the parenthesis)

```
SELECT
      FYDates.ShowDate,
      FYDates.WeekBeginning,
      count(*) as Entries,
      count( distinct MT.my_user_id ) as DistinctEntries,
   from
      my_table MT
         JOIN ( TheEntireQueryAsIsFromAbove ) as FYDates
         ON MT.Created_At >= FYDates.WeekBeginning
         AND MT.Created_At < FYDates.WeekEnding
   where
      MT.my_group_id = 123123
   group by
      FYDates.ShowDate,
      FYDates.WeekBeginning
   order by
      FYDates.WeekBeginning
```

Notice the JOIN to the sub-query.  It is based on the entry CreatedAt GREATER OR EQUAL to the computed beginning week and LESS THAN the ENDING DATE  (thus up to 11:59:59pm).

Now, you need to run it again for another week?  You can actually parameterize this for the inner default declarations of the

```
      ( select 
              @WeekFrom := date_sub( '2017-10-01', interval 7 day ), 
              @WeekNum := 41,
              @FiscalYr := 2017 ) sqlvars
```

The only difference here is that the result will be in ROWS instead of columns, but which works better for performance, readability, updates for future fiscal weeks, etc.  I would rather see a list of 52 rows down a single page than 208 columns wide, but that might just be me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to convert that query to regular `GROUP BY`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b600c5/1

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%u') AS yearweek_week,  
    COUNT(my_user_id) AS total_week, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT my_user_id) AS distinct_week
FROM my_table
WHERE my_group_id = 123123
AND created_at BETWEEN '2017-10-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-03 00:00:00'
GROUP BY yearweek_week
```

All the rest logic like finding the first day of a week and to get all weeks if we miss some data for some weeks in the year you can do on backend app whatever language you use.

Or you can improve the query to get them all even if there is no data, but that will still be much more performant than your approach.

But even my approach is not really good against big data set. so to improve that I would recommend to add another indexed column 'yearweek' and update values when needed - that way we can get rid of dynamic formatting. And just do `SELECT yearweek AS yearweek_week,`